# Electronic health record that is exposed to FHIR server

Tags: hl7-fhir

Can anyone tell me any real Electronic health record that is present on FHIR server? I want to predict hospital readmission on such data.

Answer (score 1):

There is real data available from numerous EHRs, but you will only be able to access the data if you are a patient (in which case you can only access your own data), you're a provider with organization whose data is managed by the EHR (in which case you'll only have access to data you have a right to see as a provider), or you have a data sharing arrangement with the organization - which will typically mean you'll get access to a de-identified clone of the production data.